# how do i load a php page with lots of image and text using jquery ajax api?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, load, request

While requesting a php page from the server using .load() api, or for that matter the .ajax() api of jquery, should the php page be a complete one with all the   tags and markings, and also the should it have the database connection details in it?

I tried linking the php page using .load() but it does not seem to work. My php page that is being requested would have lots of images and stuff in it. How do I have this php page displayed using the load() api?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the best practice is to load the resource you want to update dynamically,i.e. only load a partial page.

When loading full pages, it's likely that you're loading a lot of data that you don't need.

Instead, I'd make a block with the html/images/script that you want to update dynamically, and just load this.

### Example

#### Main page

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>About me</h1>
    <p>Some data about me</p>
    <div class="latest-photos">&nbsp;</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Gallery resource - gallery.block.php

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="myphoto1.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="myphoto2.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### Script

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(".latest-photos").load("gallery.block.php");
});
```

Comment: thanks for the code, i can elaborate on this example. In the php code you hardcoded the images src. In the scenario I am working on, these would instead come from a database. So the question is, should this php page have all the database connection details as well- since the page which makes this request has already connected to db.

Comment: also, in my scenario, the master page which makes the request has all the styling in an external css. the master page then makes the request for the php page using .load() api. Will the styling, as applicable, be applied to this ajax loaded sub-page as well, or should the styling for the ajax loaded part be seperately called for?

Comment: To the first question, I would use a database connection in the block page too (gallery.block.php). This would also allow you to reuse blocks between pages (even if some do not have db connection).

Comment: Second question. Yes, the styling would apply to the loaded content as well. If you prefer, it is possible to include inline styles in the loaded block too.

Answer (score 0):

If your php page needs a database connection you have to specify everything in it in order to display your images.

Another thing, when using the load method, it's not necessary that your called page should have a complete html structure.

```
$("#container").load("page.php");
```